# Firebase Storage (admin): create reference with downloadURL

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

How can I create a reference to a file in Cloud Storage within a Cloud Function while "only" having the downloadURL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you want to derive the `bucket` and `file` names from a `downloadURL`.

If you look at the format of a `downloadURL` you will find that it is composed as follows:

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/<your-project-id>.appspot.com/o/<your-bucket-name>%2F<your-file-name>?alt=media&token=<a-token-string>
```

So you just need to use a set of Javascript methods like `indexOf()`, `substring()` and/or `slice()` to extract the bucket and file names from the `downloadURL`.

Then you could do something like the following, according to https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.0.x/File:

```
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage();
const bucket = storage.bucket('<your-bucket-name>');

const file = bucket.file('<your-file-name>');
```

Comment: @ktm125 Hello, you may also upvote my answer, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up Thanks!!